# WooThumbs: Product gallery images are loading slow

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I installed "WooThumbs - Awesome Product Imagery" plugin on my WooCommerce site to display the product gallery nicer. I found that the thumbnails generated by WooThumbs are loading slow or sometime I need to refresh the page to have them loaded.

I first thought it was the thumbnails/product image gallery size are too large. But it is about 150kb per image which I think is good ?

This is [the link](http://gplanter.mysignbox.com/product/florinoid/) to a single product of my site. Can anyone give me some ideas to improve this ?

Below is the picture which shows it is in loading state:
[image]

Thanks a lot,
CK

Comment: 3 things may make a gallery slow : Size of single image, number of images, and plugin making some picture work... Are your thumbs dynamically generated ?

Comment: Hi, Random. My thumbs are not dynamically generated.

Comment: The reason is that this plugin is generating a javascrip error with this js: `jck_woothumbs/assets/frontend/js/main.min.js`. the error in the browser console is: `TypeError: z.reloadSlider is not a function. (In 'z.reloadSlider(n())', 'z.reloadSlider' is undefined)`… You have to open a ticket or a thread in support pages of this plugin.